# Disable ALT+drag Xubunto

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I'm tring to Disable `ALT+drag` Xubunto as this intereferes with OBS's `Alt+drag` to crop windows. I found a few possible solution about ubunto gnome and lubunto but they did't work.

I assume it has something to do with `"windows manager>shortcuts"` theres an option called `"move window"` I changed it to `super` but it didn't fix anything. I tried installing tweaks but it didn't have any relevant option!

Maybe if I serche in the confic file the shortcut... but I'm not familiar with linux to know where to find it...

Also this only became a problem today last few it want a problem... only things I did diferent was: instaling Komorebi and turning on focus fallow mouse. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

### Change your default window grabbing key

Go to `Settings Manager` > `Window Manager Tweaks` > `Accessibility` and change **Key used to grab and move windows** to another different from `ALT`

[image: xfwm4 tweaks window]

Logoff and login again.

Source: [XFCE Window Manager Tweaks Wiki](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/wmtweaks#accessibility)